# Java byte[] pointer conversion

Tags: java

I have a method given these arguments

```
int read( byte result[], int offset, int size ) {
}
```

From which I need to call a different method:

```
int read( byte result[], int length ) {
}
```

I know how to convert an array in C++ with an offset, but I have no idea how to do this in Java.

Comment: You can't. You have to create a copy of the sub-array.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, would you mind posting this as the answer?

Comment: raw pointers are not supported by java. use System.arrayCopy or Arrays.copyOf or manual copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You have to create a copy of the sub-array.

Easiest way to do that, is to use one of the [`Arrays.copyOfRange(xxx[] original, int from, int to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#i29) methods, where `xxx` is a primitive type or any object type.

If needed, you can copy updated values back to the original array using [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).

In your case, the parameter is actually output-only, so you just create a new array, call the method with it, then copy the values to the original array, e.g.

```
int read( byte result[], int offset, int size ) {
    if (offset == 0)
        return read(result, size);
    byte[] buf = new byte[size];
    int bytesRead = read(buf, size);
    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, result, offset, bytesRead);
    return bytesRead;
}
```